separation time of points have 'positive upper density' under positive topological entropy?
Let $(X,d)$ be a compact metric space and $g:X\to X$ be a continuous map on $X$. A subset $K$ of $X$ is called $(n,\epsilon)$ separated if, for any two distinct points $x$, $y$ of $K$ there exists $i\in\{0,1,2,\dots,n-1\}$ such that $d(g^i(x),g^i(y))> \epsilon$. let $S_n(g,\epsilon)$ denote the largest cardinality of an $(n, \epsilon)$-separated set. Then the topological entropy of $g$ is denoted by $h_{\rm top}(g)$ and is defined by $h_{\rm top}(g)=\lim_{\epsilon \to 0+} \limsup\limits_{n \to \infty}{\frac{\log S_{n}(g, \epsilon)}{n}}.$
Assume $g$ has positive entropy. This means that for small enough $\epsilon$ there is a sequence $n_k \to \infty$ so that $S_{n_k}(g, \epsilon)>e^{c n_k}$ for some $c>0$. Then my questions are the following.

For each $k$ does there exist a nonempty set  $A_k \subset X$ and a natural number $t_k \in {0,1,2,\dots,n_k-1 }$ so that for each pair $x,y$ from  $A_k$ we have, $d(g^{t_k}(x),g^{t_k}(y))>\epsilon$ with $\limsup\limits_{k \to \infty}{\frac{t_k}{n_k}}>0$?

If there is such $A_k$, then what can we say about $m(k)$, the maximal cardinality of such $A_k$'s? For instance, can we say something about how $m(k)$ grows or evolves with $k$?

For each $k$ is there a pair $x_k \neq y_k$ from $X$ and a number $1 \leq t_k \leq n_k$ so that  $d(g^{t_k}(x),g^{t_k}(y))>\epsilon$ with $\limsup\limits_{k \to \infty}{\frac{t_k}{n_k}}>0$. and $d(x_k,y_k)<a_k$ where $a_k \to 0$? Can we strengthen the condition to $\liminf\limits_{k \to \infty}{\frac{t_k}{n_k}}>0$? Can we make $a_k \to 0$ exponentially fast?

If the previous answer is affirmative then how many such pairs are there?

In all of the above questions can $t_k$ be substituted as the first time before $n_k$ when  $d(g^{t_k}(x),g^{t_k}(y))>\epsilon$ happens?


Sorry for this long and possibly naive question. But any answer or comment will be extremely helpful. Thanks.

Commenting first to try to get some clarification. For (1), the answer is trivially yes; just take $t_k = n_k - 1$ and $x,y$ with distance $\epsilon$ after $n_k - 1$ iterations (you can assume surjectivity WLOG by replacing $X$ with the limit set $\bigcap g^n(X)$, which shouldn't affect entropy). I imagine you meant something else, but I'm not sure what.

You are right! I was thinking about how to rephrase the question but I couldn't come up with a way yet. I hope to correctly phrase it soon. Thank you for pointing it out!
